# Javascript Array unshift new Date subtracting 1 Day

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am getting some strange results from the following code:

```
a = [];
a[0] = new Date();
console.log("1 Element Added: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());

//"1 Element Added: 1 - Sun Jun 02 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"


a.unshift(new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(a[0].getDate() - 1))));
console.log("First Unshift: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());

//"First Unshift: 2 - Sat Jun 01 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sun Jun 02 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"


a.unshift(new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(a[0].getDate() - 1))));
console.log("Second Unshift: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());

//"Second Unshift: 3 - Fri May 31 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sat Jun 01 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sun Jun 02 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"


a.unshift(new Date(new Date(new Date().setDate(a[0].getDate() - 1))));
console.log("Third Unshift: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());

//"Third Unshift: 4 - Sun Jun 30 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Fri May 31 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sat Jun 01 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sun Jun 02 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```

Same code works 1st and 2nd time, but the 3rd run gives an unexpected result - it should be Thu May 30 2019, not Jun 30 2019 Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what's with the repeated `new Date( new Date( new Date( ... )))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The innermost `new Date()` always makes a Date instance in June. When you set the day-of-month to 30, you're forcing the date to June 30th, not May 30th.

Calling `.setDate()` *can* change the month, but only when the day-of-month is something that doesn't make sense, either smaller (zero or negative) or bigger (like 33). Since 30 is indeed a real day in June, the month doesn't change.

Comment: You should mention that the third time it sets the data to May because the parameter passed to `setDate` is `0`.

Comment: I think I understand what you are saying... it works the second time since there is no June 31st, but there is a June 30th.  So how can I create a new date object at the beginning of the array and subtracting one day based on the adjacent array object?

Comment: @Bob you can use something like this: `a.unshift(new Date(new Date(a[0]).setDate(a[0].getDate() - 1)));`. The important part is `new Date(a[0])`, you need to construct a new date that has the same value as the previous one and then subtract one day.

Answer (score 1):

@Pointy and @Titus have already explained why the code does not work as you expected. Here I leave your code modified to react as you wanted:

```
a = [];
a[0] = new Date();
console.log("1 Element Added: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());

//"1 Element Added: 1 - Sun Jun 02 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

a.unshift(new Date(a[0]));
a[0].setDate(a[0].getDate()-1);
console.log("First Unshift: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());

//"First Unshift: 2 - Sat Jun 01 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sun Jun 02 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"


a.unshift(new Date(a[0]));
a[0].setDate(a[0].getDate()-1);
console.log("Second Unshift: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());

//"Second Unshift: 3 - Fri May 31 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sat Jun 01 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),Sun Jun 02 2019 12:13:35 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"


a.unshift(new Date(a[0]));
a[0].setDate(a[0].getDate()-1);
console.log("Third Unshift: "+a.length + " - " + a.toString());
```